# Request a Steam marketprice item lowest value

Tags: php

So what I'm trying to do is to assign the lowest marketprice value to a variable and then print it.
I'm not sure how to do that, all I can is print the whole request.

```
<?php
$value = file_get_contents('http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=US&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=StatTrak%E2%84%A2%20P250%20%7C%20 Steel%20Disruption%20%28Factory%20New%29');
echo $value;
?>
```

How can I assign the "lowest_price" to a $variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like json to me, so you could extract it by using this here:

```
$value = file_get_contents('http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=US&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=StatTrak%E2%84%A2%20P250%20%7C%20 Steel%20Disruption%20%28Factory%20New%29');
$json = json_decode($value);
$variable = $json->lowest_price;
echo $variable;
```

So you might look also at this: http://www.w3schools.com/json/

Comment: It still dosen't show anything, I think the problem is at "$variable = $json->lowest_price;"

Comment: try to var_dump($value, $json); it will show you, what is in the vars.